# How to fix undefined variable (query) and fatal error (uncaught error) in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta CHARSET="UTF-8" />
    <title> PHP TASK 3 RESULTS PAGE - VT211 </title>
</head>
<style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 2px Solid black
    }
</style>
<body>

    <?php
    $servername = "dragon.kent.ac.uk";
    $username = "co583";
    $password = "co583";
    $dbname = "co583";

    //Try connecting to DB server

    $DBconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    try {
        $dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        echo "Connected succssfulluy" . "<br>";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
    ?>

    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['cid']) && $_GET['cid'] == 'C01') {
        $query = $DBConn->prepare(
            "SELECT surname, forename, dob, gender FROM member WHERE clubID = 'C01' ORDER BY surname ASC, forename ASC"
        );
        $query->execute();
    }
    ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Forename</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['forename']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['surname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['dob']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to link this page to a main page which is working, however when I run the code to this page it says I have a undefined query on line 54 which I can't seem to see why it isn't working and on the same line a fatal error regarding the fetch function. Any help?

Here are the error messages;

> Notice: Undefined variable: query in /teaching/proj/comp5830/php/vt211/public_html/results_page.php on line 54

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on null in /teaching/proj/comp5830/php/vt211/public_html/results_page.php:54 Stack trace: #0 {main}thrown in /teaching/proj/comp5830/php/vt211/public_html/results_page.php on line 54

Comment: On line 36 you have an `if` where you define a variable, but then later you use it regardless of the `if`.

Comment: Falta no while vc colocar PDO::FETCH_ASSOC entre os parenteses da função fetch,